# How to orderBy Jpa criteria query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpa-criteria

I've got InvestmentDTO

```
public class InvestmentDTO {
    
    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private InvestmentTypeDTO investmentTypeDTO;

    public InvestmentDTO() {
    }

    public InvestmentDTO(int id, String code, String name, InvestmentTypeDTO investmentTypeDTO) {
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.investmentTypeDTO = investmentTypeDTO;
    }
// getters, setters
```

And I create criteriaQuery:

```
CriteriaQuery<InvestmentDTO> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(InvestmentDTO.class);
Root<Investment> investmentRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Investment.class);
Join<Investment, InvestmentType> investmentTypeJoin = investmentRoot.join("investmentType", JoinType.LEFT);

criteriaQuery.select(
    criteriaBuilder.construct(InvestmentDTO.class,
        investmentRoot.get("id"),
        investmentRoot.get("code"),
        investmentRoot.get("name"),
            criteriaBuilder.construct(
                InvestmentTypeDTO.class,
                investmentTypeJoin.get("id"),
                investmentTypeJoin.get("name")
            )
        )
    );
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(investmentRoot.get("id")));
List<InvestmentDTO> results = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

If I remove line `criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(investmentRoot.get("id")));`
Query is fine and returns result without exception
But with that line I have exception:
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5`
full trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter$SqmAliasedNodePositionTracker.resolveSqlSelection(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:8290) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping.resolveSqlSelection(BasicAttributeMapping.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping.createDomainResult(BasicAttributeMapping.java:307) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.AbstractSqmPathInterpretation.createDomainResult(AbstractSqmPathInterpretation.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationArgument.buildArgumentDomainResult(DynamicInstantiationArgument.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiation.lambda$createDomainResult$0(DynamicInstantiation.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiation.createDomainResult(DynamicInstantiation.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationArgument.buildArgumentDomainResult(DynamicInstantiationArgument.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiation.lambda$createDomainResult$0(DynamicInstantiation.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiation.createDomainResult(DynamicInstantiation.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.lambda$visitSelection$23(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2294) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonList.forEach(Collections.java:4966) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelection(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2289) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectClause(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2207) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2051) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:435) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmQuerySpec.accept(SqmQuerySpec.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.spi.BaseSemanticQueryWalker.visitQueryPart(BaseSemanticQueryWalker.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQueryPart(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1909) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1594) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:435) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSelectStatement.accept(SqmSelectStatement.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.translate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:771) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:345) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
        at com.example.lazy.controller.InvestmentController.getDTO(InvestmentController.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2022